# Does the UN Security Council votes 14-0 to condemn Israeli settlement have binding consequences for Israel?

Tags: international-law, united-nations, israel, palestine

UN Security Council passed [Resolution 2334 (2016)](http://www.un.org/webcast/pdfs/SRES2334-2016.pdf) 14-0 condemning the construction of Israeli settlements in east Jerusalem and the West Bank. The resolution called continuing construction in the Palestinian territory a “flagrant violation” of international law, and it called on Israel to halt all settlement activities in order to salvage a two-state solution.

The U.S. abstained from the vote, in a departure from past U.S. diplomatic practice of vetoing such a resolution in support of Israel.

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/u-n-security-council-votes-14-0-to-condemn-israeli-settlement-construction/

The US did not use its veto power during the vote and allowed a censure. New Zealand, Malaysia, Venezuela and Senegal, who were co-sponsors of the draft resolution, have requested the vote, which diplomats said was to take place at 1900GMT.

Does this UN resolution have any binding consequences for Israel?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? (1) "What does this mean?" — seems to be too broad; and (2) "Will Israel stop...?" — we can't foretell the future.

Comment: I think what you actually mean to ask (and what would be a valid question) is if this UN resolution has any binding consequences for Israel.

Comment: @Philipp, Yes. and also want to know if Israel would be more cautious about any future resettlements

Comment: @Philipp The UN definition of *"settlement"* is anything that had Jews move in after 1928 as well as any area that the Arabs removed Jews from at any time in the past (including Jerusalem).

Comment: Various comments deleted. Please note that comments are for clarifying and improving the question, not for stating your political opinion about the matter of the question.

Comment: @Killer066 We would like to know too if Israel will be more careful in the future, but unfortunately we are not able to see the future. So this would be entirely speculative.

Comment: ￼[Vijay Prashad](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/Tel-Aviv-on-tenterhooks/article16955092.ece) suggests that 2334 may allow the ICC to investigate Israel's colonisation activities.

Answer (score 9):

No, this resolution has no direct binding consequences for anyone. UN resolutions *can* contain instructions UN members are obligated to follow. But this one is merely a statement of opinion and intent without defining any actual actions or concrete threats of actions.

Politically it can be seen as a declaration of which countries' governments stand on which side of the Israel/Palestine conflict.

But Israel has already taken consequences from this resolution [by cancelling all foreign aid to Senegal](http://www.jpost.com/Israel-News/Politics-And-Diplomacy/Jerusalem-orders-to-cancel-all-aid-programs-to-resolution-co-sponsor-Senegal-476421), one of the countries which co-sponsored the resolution.

The future will tell if any of the countries which voted for this resolution will take any concrete measures with the goal to hinder the Israel settlement programs and if and how Israel will react to this.

Comment: Comments deleted. As I said, the backgrounds of this resolution are not part of this question. So please post this somewhere else. We are a Q&A site, not a debate club.